find-symbol requires explicit package name
Solving a challenge in www.codewars.com.
It uses sbcl and rove for testing the answers.
I want to translate a string to a symbol. Codewars requires code inside a package to see it. This is a sample
(defpackage #:challenge/solution
  (:use #:cl)
  (:export #:function-to-test))
(in-package #:challenge/solution)

(defun function-to-test (str)
  (let ((symbols (print '(A B C D E F G H I))))
       (print (find-symbol  (string-upcase str)))
  ))

Calling
(function-to-test  "C" 1)

On my PC prints:
(A B C D E F G H I) 
C 

But on the server prints:
(CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::A CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::B CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::C
 CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::D CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::E CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::F
 CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::G CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::H CHALLENGE/SOLUTION::I) 
NIL

I need to make the symbol package explicit:
(find-symbol  (string-upcase str) :challenge/solution)

Why? Is there any workaround variable with the current file package?

You showed the definition of function-to-test, but you're calling count-patterns-from.

in-package sets the package that's used when defining the function, not when the function is called.

@Barmar, matched the function names. How can I make find-symbol search in the package set by in-package

I don't think there's an automatic way to get the load-time package.
